# Class inheritance chain and pointers to each of classes

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

So given simple code like following:

```
class A{
public:
    virtual void foo() const { cout << "foo in A." << endl;}
private:
    int a;
};

class B: public A{int c;};

class C :  public B{
public:
    void foo() const override  {cout << "foo in B." << endl;}
private:
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

now, when I create the object of type C I can imagine its layout in the memory like this:

```
+----------------+
|     C (int)    |
|+--------------+|
||    B (+1)    ||
||+------------+||
|||  A (2int)  |||
||+------------+||
|+--------------+|
+----------------+
```

so now simple code:

```
C objectC;
A* aPtr = &objectC;
B* bPtr = &objectC;
C* cPtr = &objectC;
```

I would expect, that even though compiler generates code, which makes the following expression return true:

```
(aPtr == bPtr && bPtr == cPtr)
```

the following expression should return false:

```
((int)aPtr == (int)bPtr && (int)bPtr == (int)cPtr)
```

but on my PC it returned also true. Also after printing out the numerical values of pointers they were also the same.

My question is why does the expected result did not come after running program? Is there some C++ document specifying the exact behavior of pointer's values in situations like this or it's more like compiler dependant thing?

Comment: Who says `(aPtr == bPtr && bPtr == cPtr)` has to be true?  Did you observe that?

Comment: @NathanOliver Of course in his example those pointers should compare equal (after being implicitly cast to the common base-type)

Comment: _"the following expression should return false"_ Why's that? A `C` includes its `B` subobject includes its `A` subobject. You only get differences when multiple inheritance comes into play. As for a document, yes, read the ABI used by your system & compiler.

Comment: @NathanOliver yes I observed that

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why you think the size of `B` should be `+1` the size of `A`

Comment: There is no multiple inheritance in your example

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: make it an answer.

Comment: @Leon Ah yes.  I missed it was a chain.  I was thinking about a multiple inheritance structure per the title.

Comment: @TavianBarnes it;s not +1 size of A. AFAIK if class do not have any member it's size is always one, so that you can have a table of objects of this type (C ctab[10])

Comment: True the title may be misleading. I will try to edit this. Thanks

Comment: @DawidPi But `B` *has a member* (`int c;`), and even if it didn't, it has `A` as a subobject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layout of the object is more likely to be the reverse of what you have shown.

```
+----------------+ +     +
|    A (int)     | |     |
+----------------+ |  B  |
| delta  B (2 int) |     |  C
+------------------+     |
| delta  C (int)         |
+----------------------- +
```

It makes sense that the numerical value of `aPtr`, `bPtr`, and `cPtr` will be the same when such a layout is used by a compiler.

I haven't heard of any compiler that creates an object layout like you suggested. I am not saying definitively that there aren't any, it's just that I haven't heard of them.

Comment: Could you please also tell in the answer if it can be like I suggested in question and if this is compiler/platform dependant?

Comment: @DawidPi, see my update. That's the best I can offer.